# How to get all the details from multiple tables in Cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have two different tables as Post and Post_Info.

I want to get all the details using post_id in cake php from both the tables. The Post_Info table having post_id as foreign key and other related details.

I am new to Cakephp and I don't know how to get data from multiple tables in Cakephp.

I can get data from Post table using following query in Cakephp.

Following code is getting data from Post table.

```
$userdata = $this->Post->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array('Post.post_id' => $post_id)
        ));
```

Comment: What about start by reading the manual https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you have to do two things.

1. Make a relation of belongsTo in PostInfoTable.php in your model folder. you can read more about it [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongsto-associations).
2. Once you have made the relationship all you have to do is use "contain" in your query along with the Model name. Your query will be modified as below

```html
$userdata = $this->Post->find('first', array(
                'conditions' => array('Post.post_id' => $post_id),
                'contain' => ['PostInfo']
            ));
```

And you are good to go.

Moreover, I will recommend you to go through the documentation at least once it will be a great help to you.